# Is it possible to solve for scalar in this multiplication of two quadratic forms involving inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given the following two quadratic forms:
$$a^2=\mathbf{w'Xw}$$
$$b^2=\mathbf{1'X^{-1}1}$$

And the known relations:

$$a^2b^2=1$$
$$\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{\Sigma}-\lambda\mathbf{R}$$

Where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ and $\mathbf{R}$ are symmetric positive definite matrices.

Is it possible to find a closed expression for the scalar $\lambda$?

Also known:

$$\mathbf{w'1}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\lambda$ is linear in the equation $a^2 = \mathbf w' (\mathbf \Sigma - \lambda \mathbf R) \mathbf w$.

Since $\mathbf R$ is positiv definite and $\mathbf w\ne 0$ , we have $\mathbf w'\mathbf R \mathbf w > 0$ and
$$ \lambda = \frac{\mathbf w'\mathbf\Sigma \mathbf w - a^2}{\mathbf w'\mathbf R \mathbf w}.$$

Comment: But $\lambda$ is in $a^2$.

Comment: @ben: Does $a$ depend on $\lambda$ is any other way than by the equation stated in your question?